# Why does Spring Boot not recognise a default bean from autoconfigure?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

I am trying to build a JMS consumer, but spring does not recognise configurer as a bean:

`Could not autowire. No beans of 'DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' type found.`

Here is the function:

```
    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<? extends AbstractMessageListenerContainer> factory(
            @Qualifier("connectionFactory") final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer)
            {
        return getJmsListenerContainerFactory(connectionFactory, configurer);
    }
```

And these are the annotations on my class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig { ... }
```

In my pom.xml I have included the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need one of these starters, depending on which broker you are using.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

If you are using some other broker, you need to disable auto configuration of JMS and define your own infrastructure beans.